# Drawing mysql data with highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to plot data from a mysql table on document load with highcharts:
the html looks like that:

```
function FetchData(){
        //alert("Fetching");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/reports/fetch_data.php',
            success: function(data) {
                dataTemp = [];
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dataTemp.push(data[i][0]);  // '1' index for getting that temp value. '0' for date.     
                }

                c_temperature.series[0].data = dataTemp;
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dataTemp.push(data[i][1]);  // '1' index for getting that temp value. '0' for date.     
                }
                c_temperature.series[1].data = dataTemp;
                }

            });

function DrawCharts(){
        c_temperature = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'dashboard',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperatur'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    margin: 10
                }
            },
                legend:{
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits:{
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperatur',
                    data: []
                }]
        });

$(document).ready(function() {
        DrawCharts();
        FetchDevices();
        FetchData();



    });

<body>
<div id="dashboard">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
```

And the php I call looks like that:

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);#
    echo 'Connected</br>';
    $sql = "select ZEIT,FEUCHTE,TEMPERATUR,LUX,PITCH from ".$mac.
    " order by ID";

    foreach($con - > query($sql) as $row) {
        $x = $row['ZEIT'];
        /*$x = mktime()*1000;*/
        $y_h = (float) $row['FEUCHTE'];
        /*$y_t=(float)$row['TEMPERATUR'];
        $y_l=(float)$row['LUX'];
        $y_a=(float)$row['PITCH'];*/
        $ret = array($x, $y_h, /*$y_t,$y_l,$y_a,$mac*/ );
        echo json_encode($ret);
    }
    $con = null;
}
```

The php code successfully returns data. 
But I dont see a graph and debugging with the browser console does not give a clue either. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Beste Regards

Comment: Errors on browser console? Both your functions are missing the closing `}`

Comment: Also i don't see your code in script tag

Comment: You should initialise chart in callback of Ajax, because in that moment your  request is not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `c_temperature.series[0].setData(dataTemp, true);` and `c_temperature.series[1].setData(dataTemp, true);`. By setting the data, you're not actually telling highcharts to redraw the chart, so nothing is happening when you update the data.

Comment: So the Chart area is now displaying correctly but without a graph,

Comment: The Chart area is now being displayed, but there is no plot. It seems like my ajax call to fetch_data.php is not being executed. if I uncomment the line alert("fetching)"; no alert window will appear.  Is there something wrong how I'm doing the ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the order in wich you do your operations: firstly you create the chart and then you make the ajax call to fetch the data, but you are not updating the chart.

Try to move the chart creation inside the ajax success callback: first populate the series array with the data received from PHP, then construct the chart passing the serie array as a option; like this:

```
success: function(data) {

    var data_series = [];

    /* here populate the data_series array from your PHP results */

    new Highcharts.Chart({

    /* here other options... */

    series: data_series 

});
```

Comment: ok I'll try that, ajax is now successfully executing, my json echo from the php was messed up

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I'm doing now:

```
function FetchData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'php/reports/fetch_data.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var points = data;
                c_temperature = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'dashboard',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperatur'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickPixelInterval: 150,
                        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        minPadding: 0.2,
                        maxPadding: 0.2,
                        title: {
                            text: '°C',
                            margin: 10
                        }
                    },
                        legend:{
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        credits:{
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        series: points
                });

                /*dataTemp = [];
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                dataTemp.push(data[0][i]);  

                }
                c_temperature.series[0].setData(dataTemp, true);
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    dataTemp.push(data[1][i]);  

                    }
                c_temperature.series[1].setData(dataTemp, true);*/
                }

            });
    }
```

Result: it is showing the graph but still no plot.
The php return has been changed to this:

```
try {
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname" ,$username, $password);

$sql = "select ZEIT,FEUCHTE,TEMPERATUR,LUX,PITCH from ".$mac." where ID>'60080' order by ID";
$x = array();
$y_h = array();
foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row)
    {

    $x[]=$row['ZEIT'];
    $y_h[]=(float)$row['FEUCHTE'];

    $ret = array($x,$y_h);
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);

$con = null;
```

}

Comment: be sure that the data you are returning from PHP is in the correct format for highcharts